# What is the Default Session Timeout Value in Struts?

Tags: security, struts, java-security, secure-coding

I have a java code which I am reviewing for security vulnerabilities. The code is developed using Apache Struts framework. The session timeout is not being set in the code. From what I know, this indicates excessive session timeout vulnerability as long as there is no default session timeout value being set by the framework.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked for, but here you can see how to SET the timeout, at a global level and per session basis: https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/how-to-configure-the-session-timeout-in-servlet/

Answer (score 0):

As you have not set the session timeout explicitly, you can get the value of session timeout in struts using `getMaxInactiveInterval()` method of [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval()) interface.

**Code:**

```
HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();  
int timeout = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();//Returns the maximum time interval, in seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Rohit. I understood what you have mentioned.So the question is session.setMaxInactiveInterval() is not being used anywhere in the code. In addition to this, there is no <session-config> in any .xml file. Does this imply no timeout ?

Comment: There should be a default time-out, you can get that using above code. It would be same as servlet i.e 30 mins